# Android Realm RecyclerView animations not working?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a `RecyclerView` which gets populated by a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` but somehow there are no animations playing when the data changes.
The adapter class uses multiple `ViewHolders` for different layouts but that should not affect animations right?

```
public class DiaryPageEntryAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Entry, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

      static class MealEntryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
              @BindView(R.id.item_diary_entry_drink_title) TextView tvMealEntryTitle;
              @BindView(R.id.item_diary_entry_meal_time) TextView tvMealEntryTime;
              BindView(R.id.item_diary_entry_meal_bullet_list) RecyclerView rvBulletList;

         MealEntryBulletAdapter bulletAdapter;

        public MealEntryViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            this.bulletAdapter = new MealEntryBulletAdapter();
            rvBulletList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext()));
            rvBulletList.setAdapter(this.bulletAdapter);
        }

        void bindData(MealEntry mealEntry) {
            tvMealEntryTitle.setText(mealEntry.getTitle());
            tvMealEntryTime.setText(DateTimeUtils.timeValueToText(itemView.getContext(), mealEntry.getTime()));
            this.bulletAdapter.updateData(mealEntry.getConsumedMeals() ,mealEntry.getConsumedDrinks());
        }
    }

 // Other ViewHolders

    public DiaryPageEntryAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<Entry> data, boolean autoUpdate) {
        super(data, autoUpdate, true);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case MEAL_ENTRY:
                // Inflate meal entry layout and then create a new meal view holder with it
                View rowMeal = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_diary_entry_meal, parent, false);
                return new MealEntryViewHolder(rowMeal);
           // Other case options.
         }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Entry entry = getItem(position);

        if(Entry.isMealEntry(entry)) {
            MealEntryViewHolder mealHolder = (MealEntryViewHolder) holder;
            mealHolder.bindData(Entry.getMealEntryFromEntry(entry));
        }
    // Other if branches.
  }

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Entry entry = getItem(position);

        if(Entry.isMealEntry(entry)) return MEAL_ENTRY;
      // Other if branches.
     }
```

The code for setting up the `RecyclerView` and adapter looks as following:

```
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_diary_page_rv_entries);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        entryAdapter = new DiaryPageEntryAdapter(null, true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(entryAdapter);
```

The code that binds the data to the adapter is stated below:

```
RealmResults<Entry> sortedEntries = diaryEntry.getEntries()
                .where()
                .findAllSortedAsync("time");

entryAdapter.updateData(sortedEntries);
```

The auto-updates work fine but somehow no there is no animation when the data changes. A new entry simply appears but without animations. Furthermore I want a short animation to play once the RecyclerView is populated for the first time - an entrance animation similar to [http://anthony-skr.com/article/recyclerview-items-animation-with-rebound-effect][1].

**Note:** In my app´s build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
// Other dependencies
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
}
```

In the Project build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.4"
}
```

Comment: I don't see any animation code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code sample, it isn't easy to see where you call `entryAdapter.updateDate()` from, but calling this method continuously on every update will disable all animations as it just calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

A more standard pattern would look like this:

```
RealmResults<Entry> sortedEntries = diaryEntry.getEntries()
                .where()
                .findAllSortedAsync("time");
entryAdapter = new DiaryPageEntryAdapter(sortedEntries, true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(entryAdapter);
```

Animations *should* work if you do the above.